# Image view shrinks on keyboard popup in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an

1. EditText for searching items in listem
2. ListView
3. ImageView (using it as button)

When I click on the EditText the keyboard pops up and the ImageView shrinks. I tried adding: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" but didn't work. Is there any other solution.

Please check the image below:

[image]

Here is the XML I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundforprofile"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:hint="Search here..."
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".88"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listofsongs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NoFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No SONGS AVAILABLE"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutForButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".12"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addsongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/update"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </ImageView>
   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have a linear layout like this

-Search box (fixed height)

-list (.88 of remainder)

-button (.12 of remainder)

So if the remainder is 100 the height of the list is 88 and the height of the button is 12 but if the keyboard makes that remainder 50 the list height is 44 and the button height is 6.

I suggest changing the linear layout for the button (which is not really needed because it only contains 1 element) from `layout_weight=.12` to `layout_height=wrap_content` and setting a wrap content (or fixed) height on the imageview.